# Canvas App Integration issue

Tags: canvas

When I try to call ajax call from connected app and trying to send data from connected app to salesfore i get below error message.

Failed to execute "PostMessage" on "DomWindow". The target origin provided (https://c.cs9.visualfoce.com) does not match the recipient Window's origin.

Answer (score 0):

What is the other Application that you are using ? is the Other Application also using Https ? normally this would happen if other application is not using SSL or is being redirected to an http protocol.